# $cookieStore is undefined - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am new to Angular and I am trying to understand how to set and retrieve cookies in my application. I am successful setting and getting cookies using ngCookies module so far but I am stuck in a place where I can't pass them as a url parameter in my $resource requests. My services.js file looks like so:

```
angular.module('airlineServices', ['ngResource', 'ngCookies'])
    .factory('Airport', function($resource, $cookieStore){
        return $resource("http://angulairapi.rohanchhabra.in/airports/:airportCode", {
            'auth_token': function($cookieStore){
                return $cookieStore.get('auth_token');
            }
        }, {
            query: { method: "GET", isArray: false }
        });
    })
    .factory('Flight', function($resource){
        return $resource("http://angulairapi.rohanchhabra.in/flights");
    })
    .factory('Reservation', function($resource){
        return $resource("http://angulairapi.rohanchhabra.in/reservations/:id");
    });
```

Now in the when I am setting auth_token in the URL parameters section, I am trying to set using a callback function.

When I return the raw value of the auth_token, it works, but when I try to do it dynamically by retrieving a cookie that I have stored in my browser, I get an error like so:

```
Error: $cookieStore is undefined
.auth_token@http://localhost/angulair/js/services.js:5:5
r/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular-resource.min.js:6:487
r@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:7:390
```

and so on....

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess u need to remove second declaration of $cookieStore: 'auth_token': function($cookieStore) <- here. When u write $cookieStore in controller/factory function -- this means injection. when u write it in usual function -- u just name your local variable.

Comment: Wow! That was a dumb mistake. Works like a charm now. Post an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the second declaration of `$cookieStore: 'auth_token': function($cookieStore) <- here.`

I was unintentionally renaming my local variable by trying to pass it as an argument.